# Why did Nadeko use different names for Araragi?

Tags: monogatari-series

Episode 12, the story about Otorimonogatari, contains the story Nadeko Medusa. Nadeko said this:

> Favorite big brother: Koyomi Oniichan
>
> In Love with: Araragi Koyomi

why she said it differently? Does it mean that she consider Araragi as two different person? Because in Monogatari Series Second Season she turn out to be a

> yandere, and want to kill Araragi, the man that she love.

Comment: …Or, or! It could just be that it sounded neater using two different ways to address Koyomi instead of repeating the same way twice in such an intense scene, so it wouldn't seem out of place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference emphasizes the extent of her love towards Araragi: she loves Araragi as a big brother figure **as much as** she loves Araragi as a man.

> Favorite big brother: Koyomi Oniichan

This is the love of a sister for her big brother. *Sibling love*.

The honorific *onii-chan* shows that she holds Araragi very dear and sees him as if he were her real big brother.

> In Love with: Araragi Koyomi

This is the love of a girl for a boy. *Boy-girl love*.

The absence of honorific, which is a stark contrast to the previous line, shows that she loves Araragi as a member of opposite sex, not just love between sibling.

Answer (score 0):

The Oniichan has nothing to do with who she is. Oniichan is the honorific used when addressing an older brother. If you'll see, it's listed as "favorite big brother" before referring to him as "oniichan".

You can check out [this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_honorifics) for a full list of Japanese honorifics.